# What is the UA "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; adscanner/)/1.0 (http://seocompany.store; spider@seocompany.store)" doing on my web server?

Tags: user-agent

Since a few days ago, I have *lots* of web request from one or more  user agents that identify themselves with `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; adscanner/)/1.0 (http://seocompany.store; spider@seocompany.store)`. Typically, they request the same 4 to 5 URL approximately 100 to 200 times a day only to select another set of URLs the next day.

I don't understand what this UA is doing exactly, especially given that it requests the same URL multiple times in short succession.

Answer (score 1):

That bot developer has not made any information available online publicly (as far as I can tell by searching Google), and the pattern of access you described does not show any specific intent as far as I see it.

To answer your question directly, **it's not possible to know for sure what the bot is doing on your web server**, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

If it's really causing an issue, see if you can ask it to go away by using `robots.txt`, or just ban it by user agent (or by IP, but it shouldn't come down to that).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://user-agents.net/bots/adscanner-bot the bot belongs to `https://adscanner.tv/`
Maybe it analyze ad topics as they seem to offer insights about market trends.

I also saw it in my logfiles. It mostly crawls my index page.